# MYSQL: Formatting values of a column in the output

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a table which looks as below:

```
id   name   value
123  name1  ,
345  name2  N/A
456  name3  ,value1
```

I want my output to be like

```
id   name   value
123  name1  undefined
345  name2  undefined
456  name3  value1
```

If it is just `,` or `N/A` then output should be `undefined`
otherwise replace `,` from beginning of  `value`

```
Select id, name 
    (case when value regexp ',' then 'undefined'
          when value regexp 'N/A' then 'undefined'
        end)
```

However, it is replacing everything with value `undefined`

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `regexp` instead of `=` or `LIKE`?

Comment: no there is no such reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, we don't care about replacing comma(s) from value. Then, replace comma with empty string and then get the length

```
LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',', ''))=0
```

If that is `0`, then value had only `,`.

```
Select id, name, 
    (case when value = 'N/A' then 'undefined'
          when LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',', ''))=0 then 'undefined'
          else REPLACE(value, ',', '')
        end) value from <table_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples way would be to do:

```
select id, name,
  case 
    when value in (',','N/A') then 'undefined'
    when value like ',%' then substring(value,2)
    else value 
  end
```